# connectedComponents in opencv (Python) does not care from connectivity?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.3

I have a problem with `connectedComponents` (or `connectedComponentsWithStats`) which is an opencv (3.3.0) function in Python (2.7.12). A simple code is the following :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.zeros((4,4), dtype = np.uint8)
img[1,1] = 255
img[2,2] = 255
output = cv2.connectedComponents(img, 4)
print output[1]
```

It returns

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

which is strange since I asked for connected components with connectivity 4 (not 8). So the two pixels in `(1, 1)` and `(2, 2)` are not connected and should give two different connected components, labelled 1 and 2 for instance.

Did I make a mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replacing

```
output = cv2.connectedComponents(img, 4)
```

by

```
output = cv2.connectedComponents(img, connectivity=4)
```

will give you

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 2 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

Alternatively provide all 3 arguments

```
output =  cv2.connectedComponents(img, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
```

I'm not 100% why. I'll leave that to the Python experts out there. From my understanding `cv2.connectedComponents(img, 4)` should work just fine. But it doesn't